# Parse NiceHash JSON in Swift 4

Tags: json, swift, swift4

I'm working on an app to get one's balance from NiceHash api. The JSON I have to work with looks like this:

```
{
   "result":{
      "stats":[
         {
            "balance":"0.00000124",
            "rejected_speed":"0",
            "algo":5,
            "accepted_speed":"0"
         },
         {
            "balance":"0.00000163",
            "rejected_speed":"0",
            "algo":7,
            "accepted_speed":"0"
         },
         {
            "balance":"0.00114271",
            "rejected_speed":"0",
            "algo":8,
            "accepted_speed":"0.0002237"
         },
         {
            "balance":"0.00009395",
            "rejected_speed":"0",
            "algo":14,
            "accepted_speed":"0"
         },
         {
            "balance":"0.0000097",
            "rejected_speed":"0",
            "algo":20,
            "accepted_speed":"0"
         },
         {
            "balance":"0.00000004",
            "rejected_speed":"0",
            "algo":21,
            "accepted_speed":"0"
         },
         {
            "balance":"0.00128791",
            "rejected_speed":"0",
            "algo":22,
            "accepted_speed":"0"
         },
         {
            "balance":"0.0000005",
            "rejected_speed":"0",
            "algo":23,
            "accepted_speed":"0"
         },
         {
            "balance":"0.00310707",
            "rejected_speed":"0",
            "algo":24,
            "accepted_speed":"0.0000002"
         },
         {
            "balance":"0.00002411",
            "rejected_speed":"0",
            "algo":26,
            "accepted_speed":"0"
         },
         {
            "balance":"0.00000007",
            "rejected_speed":"0",
            "algo":27,
            "accepted_speed":"0"
         },
         {
            "balance":"0.0000047",
            "rejected_speed":"0",
            "algo":28,
            "accepted_speed":"0"
         },
         {
            "balance":"0.00001291",
            "rejected_speed":"0",
            "algo":29,
            "accepted_speed":"0"
         }
      ],
      "payments":[

      ],
      "addr":"some_bitcoin_adress"
   },
   "method":"stats.provider"
}
```

I want to sum all of the values of "balance" but I'm not sure how to access it. My code right now looks like this:

```
struct stats: Codable {
    let balance: String
    let rejected_speed: String
    let algo: String
    let accepted_speed: String
}
struct result: stats {
    let stats: stats
}
```

and the function to get the JSON:

```
func updateBalance() {
    let sampleDataAdress = "nicehash_link_here"
    let url URL(string: sampleDataAdress)!
    let jsonSata = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
    let data = try? jsonDecoder.decode(Array<stats>.self, from jsonData)
    data?.count
    dump(data?.first)
}
```

I hoped I would get at least the first stat but I'm getting nil instead. It's kinda my first time doing JSON in Swift 4 and I guess this code is just rubbish.

Comment: It is Swift naming convention to name your structures starting with an uppercase letter. Btw you should use URLSession to download your json data asynchronously

Comment: You are using the wrong type for the algo property it should be an Int instead of a String.

Comment: You should add structure, that has name for example "Response", and this structure must contain property of your "result" structure. And finally parse  "Response" structure using jsonDecoder.decode(Response.self, from jsonData) instead of your jsonDecoder.decode(Array<stats>.self, from jsonData)

Comment: Rather than ignoring the thrown error with `try?`, use `try` in a do-catch block and print the thrown error. It'll tell you *exactly* what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of issues.

First of all to avoid confusion name structs always capitalized. However your `stats` struct contains more confusion than just the naming.

Look at the JSON structure. There is

- A *root* dictionary with a dictionary for key `result`

  ```
  struct Root : Decodable {
      let result : Result
  }
  ```
- The *result* dictionary with an array for key `stats`

  ```
  struct Result: Decodable {
      let stats: [Stats]

      var sumOfBalances : Double {
          return stats.flatMap{ Double($0.balance) }.reduce(0.0, +)
      }
  }
  ```
- The *stats* array

  ```
  struct Stats: Decodable {

      private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
          case balance, rejectedSpeed = "rejected_speed", algo, acceptedSpeed = "accepted_speed"
      }

      let balance: String
      let rejectedSpeed: String
      let algo: Int
      let acceptedSpeed: String
  }
  ```

The value for key also is `Int` (no double quotes), not `String`

Now decode the object and get the sum of balances

```
do {
    let root = try jsonDecoder.decode(Root.self, from jsonData)
    print(root.result.sumOfBalances)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

**Note**:

Never load data synchronously from a remote URL with `Data(contentsOf`. You will block the current thread and the app will crash reliably if an error occurs. Use asynchronous API like `URLSession / URLSessionDataTask` and add proper error handling.

Comment: Why not Codable?

Comment: It seems that the objects will be never **en**coded.

Comment: You could also add a computed property to Result `var sum: Double {
        return stats.flatMap{Double($0.balance)}.reduce(0,+)
    }`

Comment: Similar? `.0` it is not needed

Comment: @LeoDabus I know that but I'm using always the proper literal type for better readability.

Comment: @LeoDabus Hey thanks! I'm new to this stuff and I appreciate your response. While I think the code now is alright I'm getting "[BoringSSL] Function boringssl_context_get_peer_sct_list: line 1757 received sct extension length is less than sct data length" in the output. Not sure what this one is about.

Comment: @kapits Sorry man I have no idea  what that error means. You should open another question and add the related code there.